# Arquillian test class variables lose value

Tags: java, junit, jboss-arquillian

I have a simple arquillian test class, with 2 test cases. The test class has a static variable, which is null at the beginning. The first test case would set a value for that variable, but when the second test starts, the value of the variable is null. I know this is not the correct way to do it, since one test depends on the other, its just for an example.

Another similar case, when I set the value of the static variable in the `@BeforeClass` method. When the first test executes, the variable will be null again. Only if i use a `@Before` method would the values be set properly, but if I have lots of tests, and the setting of the variables is time intensive then this would be a bad alternative.

I don't quite understand why this is happening. If the test is simply run as a JUnit test, then the static variables work as it should. is there any cure for this?

The test is running with a managed jboss container.

Answer (score 3):

`Junit` does not allow to share the variables between/among test cases. During execution, each test case will have its own local copy of the variables.

The rationale behind such a design is simple that test cases should not depend on each other. And that is why it is called unit testing, where each unit should be independently tested.

But if you really need to do it then you may create a `static` class variable to store the info.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! The problem is, that if the test is run with Arquillian, then the static variables which get set in the @BeforeClass will also get reinitialized. I have updated my question accordingly.

Comment: @Zuller, Don't use the same class to store the static data, u can create a separate class to hold the static data.